# storing timezone information in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, timezone

what's the best way to store information about timezone in mysql database? I don't have any information about a time, only timezone, for instance:
+02.00, -03.00 etc.
Do you think that varchar (6) will be correct?

Comment: thanks, I will read this. I'm sorry that I didn't find it earlier.

Comment: You don't have a *time zone*.  You have a *time zone offset*.  An offset is usually not useful in isolation.  Please read "Time Zone != Offset" in the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`VARCHAR(6)` is fine, but personally, i would store the offset using a signed `SMALLINT` (in minutes).

Like this, you can store numbers from `-32768` to `32767`.

You could also store it as `TINYINT` if you just want to store the hours-offset. (from `-128` to `127`)

Answer (score 1):

its all depends upon on you, but `Varchar` works for you.

```
decimal(2,2)
```

also works fine for storing time zone.
For other Date related data types are as follows

Data Type

1-`time`

2-`timestamp`

3-`date`

4-`datetime`

Comment: decimal is not optimal, because it would allow you to store for example `2.9` which you won't see as a time offset.

Comment: it allow you store your example value like wise (2.90)

Comment: i know, but it shouldn't. it would break the contract.

Comment: how its break the contract?

Comment: @steve it depends on you, its not a mysql responsibility to take care of these issues, i am only suggesting him to stor time zone kind of values.

Comment: I think it's the best way to store information, cause we can use it in queries easier than varchar type